# Designing a “statistics-Bootstrap” analysis in R

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

My intention is to come up with a bootstrap analysis of a complex data structure.

The data is as follows:

```
structure(list(pos1 = c(5, 15, 25, 40, 80, 5, 18, 22, 38, 84, 
5, 16, 50, 92, 31, 50, 20, 30, 50, 70, 27, 50, 60, 50, 90, 20, 
40, 54, 65, 78, 7, 17, 27, 42, 85, 10, 19, 25, 39, 88, 10, 19, 
55, 93, 32, 54, 22, 35, 52, 72, 29, 55, 65, 55, 95, 22, 46, 57, 
67, 79), pos2 = c(10, 17, 30, 42, 90, 10, 20, 24, 42, 87, 10, 
19, 52, 100, 40, 70, 25, 32, 60, 90, 30, 60, 71, 60, 100, 25, 
50, 50, 69, 90, 19, 27, 39, 49, 99, 20, 29, 30, 49, 92, 20, 29, 
59, 100, 48, 76, 30, 39, 67, 98, 36, 68, 76, 65, 100, 30, 55, 
55, 70, 100), chr = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), ind = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class ="factor")), .Names = c("pos1", 
"pos2", "chr", "ind"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data$pos1 and data$pos2 delimit a particular sequence in the genome at a certain chromosome (data$chr). For this example I just introduced two chromosomes. data$ind is the column for individual, so each individual have diiferent pos1 and pos2 in both chromosomes.

The process I want to follow is the following.
1.  First, from data, I want to obtain n (for this case 10 would be enough) random samples of 3 individuals (with all their pos1 and pos2 for the two chromosomes). To do that here is this piece of code:

```
rohis <- function(dat, ind, n) {
ind <- enquo(ind)
dat %>%
filter(UQ(ind) %in% sample(unique(UQ(ind)), n)) %>%
slice(sample(row_number()))
}
rohis(data, ind, 3)
```

2. Then, using all the generated random samples, my intention is to obtain bootstrap scores of each of the sequences delimited by pos1 and pos2. What is the confidence of a particular sequence delimited by pos1 pos2? There are two very important hints. First, this has to be made independently for the sequences in the two chromosomes. Second, two overlapping sequences must be considered the same.

I hope you can help me because I don’t know how I should start

Comment: For clarification, are you looking to bootstrap the `pos1` and `pos2` values across all four sequences that you have for each chromosome for each individual (e.g. chromosome 1 pos1: 7-95, pos2, sequence 2: 16-55...)? Or are these distinct sequences and you would like one value for each (e.g. chromosome 1 sequence 1: 5-15 to 8-25, sequence 2: 16-32 to 32-55...)